# <li> elements clearing the row above

Tags: html-lists, rows

Is there a way to have a list of

elements always clear the row above them without putting CSS on individual li elements?

Situation: Im building a site that's using the Business Catalyst CMS. I have a list of products which are built using lists. It all works fine except when you move the screen in and one of the product headings goes over three lines it makes the row under jump and only show one or two products instead of three.

See sample:

http://sklzaustralia.businesscatalyst.com/baseball-softball

Move the screen in until there is a gap on one of the rows. This gap is what I'm trying to avoid.

The products are imported with a module so I can add css to individual list items. It needs to be a general  or

solution.

I also know if I add a height to the

it will solve this but that makes the responsive aspect messy as I need to pick a height that works across all screen sizes. So if its right for large screen, the gap is too large for small screen layout.

An ideas on fixing this problem...?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue with an ecommerce site where product titles ranged from 2 words to 6 or more, and also included a short description underneath the product image.

You need to evaluate the elements within the

```
<div class="shop-product-small clear">
```

...and unfortunately define heights and min-heights to make sure each product div is always the same height. Play with font-size as well at a smaller @media width.

Answer (score 0):

Set the width for li to be 50% when it falls below a breakpoint (when the gap appears).
Or just add `.col-xs-6` to your li if you are using bootstrap.

Comment: Unfortunately, that won't work. They need to combat the unique variations of growing and shrinking heights of subtree elements inside the product div.